# List looks odd when text is too long

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I want a list with scrollbars, but when the content is too long, it doesn't look good:

[image]

I want it to look like this:

```
+----------------------------------------------------+
| aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa  Trashcan|
+----------------------------------------------------+
```

Here is my HTML code:

```html
<div class="col-md-7 col-sm-7 col-xs-12">
  <div>
    <div style="height: 75px;padding-bottom:0px; padding-top:0px; overflow: auto; border: 1px solid #ccc;" id="excludedDomains">
      <ul class="list-group">
        <li class="list-group-item">aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa<i style="position:relative; float:right;" class="fa fa-trash-o btn btn-danger btn-xs"></i>
        </li>
        <li class="list-group-item">
          some text
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the `list-group-item` to `d-flex` and wrap the text in a `span` using `text-truncate`:

```html
<ul class="list-group">
  <li class="list-group-item d-flex"><span class="text-truncate">aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</span><i style="position:relative; float:right;" class="fa fa-trash-o btn btn-danger btn-xs"></i>
  </li>
  <li class="list-group-item"> some text </li>
</ul>
```

https://codeply.com/p/oTEgLYk2Vv

Answer (score 1):

When your text doesn't fit in your `div`, use `word-wrap: break-word;` in your CSS.

```css
.list-group-item {
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-7 col-sm-7 col-xs-12">
  <div>
    <div style="height: 75px;padding-bottom:0px; padding-top:0px; overflow: auto; border: 1px solid #ccc;" id="excludedDomains">
      <ul class="list-group">
        <li class="list-group-item">aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa<i style="position:relative; float:right;" class="fa fa-trash-o btn btn-danger btn-xs"></i>
        </li>
        <li class="list-group-item">
          some text
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the `height` property or set it to `auto` in order to remove the vertical scrollbar.

And to remove the horizontal scrollbar, you can set `scrollbar-width: thin;`, or completely remove the scrollbar by using `none`.

And you should use the `overflow-x` property on `li`.